# How to utilize buildSrc directory with gradle?

Tags: gradle

In the gradle [documentation](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:obtaining_information_about_your_build) says:

> Builds which utilize a buildSrc directory will generate a second
>   profile report for buildSrc in the buildSrc/build directory.

How can we do that (utilize build/Src) via the gradle sript, couldn't you help me?

Comment: Make sure you are aware of difference between `build/Src` (possible path under default build directory) and `buildSrc` (described in https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources)

Answer (score 1):

You may put your helper scripts/classes to various places. One of them is [buildSrc](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources) directory. 
See below quote from gradle documentation.

> When you run Gradle, it checks for the existence of a directory called
>   buildSrc. Gradle then automatically compiles and tests this code and
>   puts it in the classpath of your build script. You don't need to
>   provide any further instruction. This can be a good place to add your
>   custom tasks and plugins.

Your qoute only tells that if you use buildSrc directory, you will have second profile report.